# How to optimize multiple join on

Tags: sql, greenplum

How to optimize a query like

```sql
select a.*,b.* from a join b
on a.foo = b.foo
and a.bar = b.bar
and a.bazz = b.bazz
-- ...(many and omitted here)
```

Is it necessary to add index on these columns so that they run faster when join?

Comment: The thumbrule of index is to have all columns in index being used in Join condition, where clause and order by clause.

Comment: I'd recommend creating a unique_ID `VARBINARY` column on Tables A (use combination of a.foo,a.bar,a.bazz to derive the ID) & B and use it for joining

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need to use indexes in an MPP database like Greenplum.  When joining really large tables, you might want to make the distribution keys the same between the two tables.

But do make sure the datatypes are the same between the tables.

Indexes aren't typically used in Greenplum.  You don't need unique indexes or primary keys either.

Answer (score -1):

It is not clear whether indexes would help.  Greenplum is a distributed database, where the data is partitioned.

So, probably the biggest impact is whether or not some or all index keys are partitioning keys for the table.

If you do add an index, then you will want one index on *all* columns being compared.  Something like `b(foo, bar, bazz)`, rather than a single index per column.